# botão zoom in/out de uma div

Tags: jquery, html, css, aplicação-web

Sabem alguma forma com jquery e/ou css simular o efeito zoom in/out de uma div. A div não têm necessáriamente uma imagem. Sem a div aumentar/dimuir, simular esse efeito para os elemento que estão contidos nela ?
Basicamente aumentar e diminuir a scala dos objectos.

Obrigado ;)

Comment: é um diagram em primefaces

Answer (score 1):

Você pode com css usar o `tranform` para aumentar o tamanho dos elementos.
Não sei se é exatamente isso que você quer mais é uma forma de dar um "zoom" em elementos no html.

```
.element {
    transform: scale(2); /* aumenta 2x o tamanho */
}
```

```css
.element{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:block;
  background:rgb(62,157,251);
  margin:100px auto;
  color:white;
  font-family:Arial;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.element:hover{
    transform:scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
</div>
```

Comment: Consigo por um botão fora da div a fazer esse efeito ? Como posso forçar em consequência de um botão acrescentar um efeito css em elementos de uma div fora ?

Comment: Sim! Consegue com javascript. Algo como `$('.button').click(function(){$('.element').toggleClass('zoom')});` e na classe zoom estar o transform `.zoom{transform:scale(2);}`